# Yii убрать валидацию с login.php?

Tags: yii

где задаются правила обязательного заполнения поля пароль\логин?

как их отключить?

хочу сделать проверку просто по имени тачки через getenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правила валидации задаются в модели, которая принимает данные, в функции `rules()`.
Если у вас форма логина - скорее всего она называется LoginForm.